# Filter table with a given date and keep rows that are greater than it in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

I got a table that I want to apply a filter on it.

```
<tr ng-repeat="log in log_list">
   <td style="text-align: center">{{log.Date}}</td>
```

I have a column with dates in this format:

```
12/10/2015 12:01:00
```

And I have a date picker:

```
<input ng-model="date3" datetime-picker date-format="MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss" close-on-select="false" />
```

with the same format.

I want to make a filter which gives the rows where dates are greater than the date I picked when I pick a date.

I can compare dates like this :

```
var date_one = '12/24/2015 03:08:14',
date_two = '12/24/2015 03:08:15';
var timeStamp_date_one = new Date(date_one).getTime() ;
var timeStamp_date_two = new Date(date_two).getTime() ;

alert(timeStamp_date_one > timeStamp_date_two)
```

Having

```
<tr ng-repeat="log in log_list | filter:date3">
   <td style="text-align: center">{{log.Date}}</td>
```

Gives me the exact row.

How do I apply this filter?

**EDIT**

Having

```
$scope.hasAcceptedDate = function(log) {
   var timeStamp_date_one, timeStamp_date_two;
   timeStamp_date_one = new Date(log.Date).getTime();
   timeStamp_date_two = new Date($scope.date3).getTime();
   return timeStamp_date_one > timeStamp_date_two;
};
```

with `| filter:hasAcceptedDate "` doesn't show me the table. Am I doing something wrong ? And I don't have console errors.

Comment: Have you read the documentation of the filter filter? https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter? All you need is `log in log_list | filter:hasAcceptedDate`, and a function `hasAcceptedDate(log)` in the scope that returns true if the log date is after `$scope.date3`, and false otherwise.

Comment: Am I missing something ? can you see the edit ?

Comment: I don't know your data. Put a breakpoint in the function and use your debugger.